# Multiprocessing queue of files in folders

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

Question is how to properly process files in Python 3.7 multiprocessing in case when I'm crawling directories recursively.

My code is as following:

```
def f(directoryout,directoryoutfailed,datafile,filelist_failed,imagefile,rootpath,extension,debug):
```

[...] some processing

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
import csv
import os
debug = 0
timeout = 20

if debug == 0:
    folder              = '/home/debian/Desktop/environments/dedpul/files/fp/'
    datafile            = 'fpdata.csv' # file with results
    directoryout        = 'fp_out' # out directory for debugging
    directoryoutfailed  = 'fp_out_failed' # out directory for wrongly processed for debuggin mode
    filelist            = 'filelist.csv' # list of processed files
    filelist_failed     = 'filelist_failed.csv' # list of wrongly processed files

counter = 0

pool = Pool(processes=4)
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(folder):
    for imagefile in files:
        rootpath = root+'/'
        fullpath = root+'/'+imagefile
        extension = os.path.splitext(imagefile)[1]
        imagefilesplit = imagefile.split('.')[0]
        counter += 1

        print('\033[93m ## ',counter,' ## \033[0m',rootpath)

        fileexist = 0
        with open(filelist) as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
            for row in csv_reader:
                if row[0] == fullpath:
                    fileexist = 1
        if fileexist == 1:
            print('    File was processed, skipping...')
            continue

        with open(filelist, mode='a') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            writer.writerow([fullpath])

        # print(directoryout,directoryoutfailed,datafile,filelist_failed,imagefile,rootpath,extension,debug)
        res = pool.apply(f, (directoryout,directoryoutfailed,datafile,filelist_failed,imagefile,rootpath,extension,debug)) 
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

1st, when I'm using pool.apply_async it uses all cores, however it doesn't process function **f()** correctly. With **pool.apply()** it works single-threading.

2nd, as you see, I'm crawling recursively list of files in folders in loop. If file was found as processed, this loop should continue. Should I do that in __ **main** __ function, or it should be moved to **f()** function? If yes, how to exchange what is during processing, which takes a few seconds per file?

3rd, function **f()** is independent, so if it will process image file and then it will add results to fpdata.csv file (or add name of not-well-processed file to **filelist_failed.csv**) and just close processing without any problems, so no real output is needed. I need just to start this function in multiprocessing.

What I am doing wrong? Should I use

```
with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
```

statement?
Before asking this query I've browsed tons of answers, but apparently it was extremely hard to find such file processing, in Python Manual as well.

Comment: What specifically goes wrong with `pool.apply_async`?

Comment: Normally it takes a few seconds to process one image, and it works fine with pool.apply (I mean, it saves data, and so on). With pool.apply_async it just runs function f(), displays info about file but no processing is done, as well info provided by function f() is not displayed. It just crowl very fastly all files

Comment: What if you save all the return values from `apply_async` in a list, and then wait for all of them to finish by iterating over the list and using `ret.get()`? Does it work ok then?

Comment: I did a test using smaller sample of files. So it FIRST loops over everything and THEN starts multiprocessing with function f()?

Comment: As soon as you call `apply_async`, it will start running `f` in a pool process. It does not wait for you to call `res.get()` to start running `f`. Calling `res.get()` on each item in the list just makes your code wait for all the background work to finish before you try to `close`/`join` the pool.

Comment: Can I say, that another words it will first collect a list of files and THEN do processing? If there is a very large number of files is any chance to start processing immediately and/or crawl file system in chunks?